# How to open last solution automatically when starting Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How do you set Visual Studio to automatically open "the last open solution" when it starts?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Tools -> Options then change the Startup option.

[image]

More Details [Check this link](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s153/visual-studio-startup.htm)

Answer (score 13):

We seem to be playing who moved my cheese.  In **Visual Studio 2022** the setting is in a new place.  It's located at `Tools` / `Options` / `Environment` / `General`

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In Visual Studio 2019 the option is *slightly* different. Select:

**Tools / Options / Startup / Most recent solution**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'll add solution for **Visual Studio Code**: use this flag in shortcut:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --reuse-window
```

[VS Code command arguments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)

Answer (score 2):

I would simply create a shortcut to your 
.Sln file, and run that.

Comment: how can you create a shortcut to the most recent solution?

Comment: I misread the question slighty. :S  I normally have 3-4 solutions on the go at any one time, so in my case shortcuts are easier rather than loading last one. But alas the question was not about this.

Comment: no worries for the missread +1(i din't gave you -1) because it's still a fine alternative.

Answer (score 2):

you go into tools-> options -> Environment -> StartUp.

Then there is an option in the "At Start Up" dropdown to load last loaded solution.